# Openmrs & MDS (mobile dispatch server) Installation

Tags: python, django, installation, mds, openmrs

I installed sana mds  in Aws ec2 . I followed the [this guide](http://dev.sanamobile.org/users/manual_install/) for installation.

When I am Trying to Access `http://<hostname>/mds/` it throwing me
Bad Request (400).

Upon Checking Apahce Error Logs I got this :

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston/handler.py:27: UserWarning:
> Handler already registered for model Event,  you may experience
> inconsistent results.
>
> "you may experience inconsistent results." % new_cls.model.**name**)

Any idea how to install MDS or how to overcome the above error message.

Answer (score 0):

I Resolved above issue by adding below line in "/opt/sana/sana.mds/mds/settings.py" ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

The link below is for Django 1.7 but explains what appears to be the source of the issue. [enter link description here](https://web.archive.org/web/20191116144537/http://docs.djangoproject.com:80/en/1.7/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)